# Is there a way to create a <style> object with React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have been asked in an interview if the following is possible (Is it?):
Is there a way to create a `<style>` Component with ReactJS.
A component, that if I inspect it in the dom inspector, will show as (for example):

```
<style>
body:{ color:red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it like this

```
<style>
    {`p {display: block}`}
</style>
```

Note the backticks

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
React.createElement("style", null, "body:{ color:red;}");
```

Or just add

```
function MyStyle(){ 
    return (
        <style>
            {` body:{ color:red;} `}
        </style>
    )
}
```

## Edit:

As said by Shmili Breuer in the other answer, the backtick `` ` `` is very import.

Why? Because if you don't use it, react will think that `{}` is a block scope and not a literal string.

Comment: The second example, where/how would u use it?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka What you are asking is a personal question. For me, I would never you such component that render a `style` tag. Some libaries like `styled-components` probably use, but I'm not sure. You can use it to generate dynamic css styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but the preferred method is to put styling on an attribute called `style`. For example:

```js
<div style={styles.container}></div>

const styles = {
  container: {
    color: 'red',
  },
};
```